# Rails creating more than one row from a single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I don't know if I am doing this in a wrong way but here is it.

I have 2 models Event and Tasks.

Event has many tasks. and task is a nested resource under event
so I first create a event and ask a user how many tasks it wants to create in it.

Let say I create a Event and a user wants to create 3 tasks in it. I want to do it in 2 steps and not one

After successful creation of event,now I go to /events/1/tasks/new

here I want to have 3 task name fields and when the user submits it, there should be 3 rows created in Task table against the Event 1

How do I achieve this

So here is the task _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@event, @task] do |f| %>
  <% if @task.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Task controller

```
def new
     @event=Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @event.task_count do
      @choice = @event.tasks.build
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @task }
    end
  end


  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = Task.new(params[:task])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
 def new
   @event=Event.find(params[:event_id])
   3.times {@event.tasks.build}  
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @task }
  end
 end
```

Comment: I tried but I get this error. @task is nil

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
 <%= form_for [@event, @task] do |f| %>
2:   <% if @task.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this choice from being saved:</h2>